# Onenter press remove innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have

```
<p contenteditable="true" data-textchanged="false">
  <button type="button" data-bind=" jqueryui: 'button', click: goto_step.bind($data, 'NCS2')">click for answer</button>
</p>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable="true" data-textchanged="false">
  <button type="button" data-bind=" jqueryui: 'button', click: goto_step.bind($data, 'NCS2')">click for answer</button>
</p>
```

but when I press enter in p tag it shows button and code will be like

```
    <p contenteditable="true" data-textchanged="false">
        <button type="button" data-bind=" jqueryui: 'button', click: goto_step.bind($data, 'NCS2')">Show script</button><p><button type="button" data-bind=" jqueryui: 'button', click: goto_step.bind($data, 'NCS2')"><br></button></p>
</p>
```

but what I need is

```
<p contenteditable="true" data-textchanged="false">
    <button type="button" data-bind=" jqueryui: 'button', click: goto_step.bind($data, 'NCS2')">Show script</button><p></p></p>
```

(here I show button but it may b any tag )
Only single p tag not button within it..I only want p tag with blank innerHTML on enter press

Answer (score 0):

hello check this code when you click on button the innerHtml is removed from p tag which id is contentToRemove. you can check link for live view link is below:

https://jsfiddle.net/fatehjagdeo/tdkj77aa/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p >
      <button type="button" class="button" >click for answer</button>
    </p>
    <p id="contentToRemove">
    anything in this p tag
    </p>

    <script>
    $(document).on('click','.button',function(){
    $('#contentToRemove').html('');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: sorry This is not what I want.. p tag is editable and on enter press it add button inside it.. I want to remove it